# How to test a laptop keyboard from its ribbon cable

Tags: test, keyboard

Is there a way to test a laptop keyboard from at its ribbon cable, fully disconnected from the motherboard? Some kind of switch continuity or something along those lines that would indicate whether a particular key is working or not. Is there a related test to do at the ribbon connector at the motherboard

Comment: Yes but you'll have to work out all the details for your particular keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

here is a useful tool at the following link.  http://www.ebay.com/itm/Laptop-Keyboard-Tester-Kit-Backlight-Test-Device-9pcs-Spare-FPC-Connectors-/111657285215